# Only 10 zones should be displayed on the screen, but it displays two more

Tags: pine-script

First of all, test the code on BINANCE:BTCUSDT Daily timeframe. I marked the zones with blue and yellow barcolors, so you can see them better.

The issue is that when you select 10 number of zones in inputs (default) and Do not shrink option (default), the code is being drunk and displays two more zones which are not even the next ones, but two candles after them. I believe it's because of the separate arrays for the bullish and bearish zones. It must be recoded in some way that it displays the correct zones. I marked the zones that should be displayed in the picture below.

## Edit:

It actually displays 5 red zones and 5 green zones I think. I expect it to display 10 zones, no matter they are bullish or bearish.

## Current

[image]

## Expected

https://www.tradingview.com/x/4DOGjqSs/

```
//@version=5
indicator("Imb", overlay = true, max_boxes_count = 500, max_bars_back = 500)

// ———————————————————— Constants {
// ————— Colors
var color GREEN         = color.green
var color RED           = color.red
var color BLUE          = color.blue
var color YELLOW        = color.yellow

// ————— Constants used in inputs
var string G1 = "Show"
var string G2 = "Hide"

var string IMB1 = "Shrink when mitigated"
var string IMB2 = "Do not shrink"
// }

// ———————————————————— Inputs {
// ————— Imbalance Zones
var GRP3 = "Imbalance Zones"
bool showImbalance = input.bool(true, "Show Imbalance/Fair Value Gaps", inline = "30", group = GRP3)
int numberOfZonesInput = input.int(10, "# Zones", inline = "31", group = GRP3)
bool updateZonesWithPriceMovement = input.string(IMB2, "", inline = "32", options = [IMB1, IMB2], group = GRP3) == IMB1
color bullishImbColorInput = input.color(GREEN, "", inline = "32", group = GRP3)
color bearishImbColorInput = input.color(RED, "", inline = "32", group = GRP3)
int imbTranspInput = input.int(80, "Transparency", inline = "32", group = GRP3)
// }

// ———————————————————— Imbalance/Fair Value Gaps {
var line bullishImbOpen = na
var line bullishImbLow = na

var line bearishImbOpen = na
var line bearishImbHigh = na

bullishImb = low > high[2]
bearishImb = high < low[2]

barcolor(bullishImb ? BLUE : bearishImb ? YELLOW : na, offset = -1, title = "Imbalance Bar Color")

plotshape(bullishImb ? bullishImb : na, style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = GREEN, offset = -1, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(bullishImb ? bearishImb : na, style = shape.triangledown, location = location.abovebar, color = RED, offset = -1, size = size.tiny)

var box[] bullishImbBox = array.new_box()
var box[] bearishImbBox = array.new_box()

var color bullColor = color.new(bullishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput)
var color bearColor = color.new(bearishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput)

if bullishImb and showImbalance
    array.push(bullishImbBox, box.new(left = time[1], top = low, right = time, bottom = high[2], extend = extend.none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, border_color = bullColor, border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = bullColor))
    if array.size(bullishImbBox) + array.size(bearishImbBox) > numberOfZonesInput
        box.delete(array.shift(bullishImbBox))

if bearishImb and showImbalance
    array.push(bearishImbBox, box.new(left = time[1], top = low[2], right = time, bottom = high, extend = extend.none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, border_color = bearColor, border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = bearColor))
    if array.size(bullishImbBox) + array.size(bearishImbBox) > numberOfZonesInput
        box.delete(array.shift(bearishImbBox))

if array.size(bullishImbBox) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(bullishImbBox) - 1
        if i <= array.size(bullishImbBox) - 1 and array.size(bullishImbBox) > 0
            t = box.get_top(array.get(bullishImbBox, i))
            b = box.get_bottom(array.get(bullishImbBox, i))
            
            // update right side of the box
            box.set_right(array.get(bullishImbBox, i), time)
            
            if updateZonesWithPriceMovement
                // delete box
                if b >= low
                    box.delete(array.remove(bullishImbBox, i))
                // update box
                else if t >= low
                    box.set_top(array.get(bullishImbBox, i), low)


if array.size(bearishImbBox) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(bearishImbBox) - 1
        if i <= array.size(bearishImbBox) - 1 and array.size(bearishImbBox) > 0
            t = box.get_top(array.get(bearishImbBox, i))
            b = box.get_bottom(array.get(bearishImbBox, i))
            
            // update right side of the box
            box.set_right(array.get(bearishImbBox, i), time)
            
            if updateZonesWithPriceMovement
                // delete box        
                if t <= high
                    box.delete(array.remove(bearishImbBox, i))
                // update box
                else if b <= high
                    box.set_bottom(array.get(bearishImbBox, i), high)
// }
```

Comment: The solution that comes to mind is, instead of two independent loops, to iterate in a single loop on the largest size between both arrays, and inside the loop, process both bull & bear zones until you reached the total limit of ten zones, taking care to check indices independently for each, so you don't generate runtime out-of-bounds errors on indices.

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF, thank you for your answer, mate! How can I do this in my case?

Comment: We explained how to do it. This isn't an indicator development service; it's a service to help Pine programmers, which supposes questions contain an attempt to program the solution. The code you're showing is just the prior version of your indicator; there's no attempt to write a solution that needs fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("Imb", overlay = true, max_boxes_count = 500, max_bars_back = 500)

// ———————————————————— Constants {
// ————— Colors
var color GREEN         = color.green
var color RED           = color.red
var color BLUE          = color.blue
var color YELLOW        = color.yellow

// ————— Constants used in inputs
var string G1 = "Show"
var string G2 = "Hide"

var string IMB1 = "Shrink when mitigated"
var string IMB2 = "Do not shrink"
// }

// ———————————————————— Inputs {
// ————— Imbalance Zones
var GRP3 = "Imbalance Zones"
bool showImbalance = input.bool(true, "Show Imbalance/Fair Value Gaps", inline = "30", group = GRP3)
int numberOfZonesInput = input.int(10, "# Zones", inline = "31", group = GRP3)
bool updateZonesWithPriceMovement = input.string(IMB2, "", inline = "32", options = [IMB1, IMB2], group = GRP3) == IMB1
color bullishImbColorInput = input.color(GREEN, "", inline = "32", group = GRP3)
color bearishImbColorInput = input.color(RED, "", inline = "32", group = GRP3)
int imbTranspInput = input.int(80, "Transparency", inline = "32", group = GRP3)
// }

// ———————————————————— Imbalance/Fair Value Gaps {
var line bullishImbOpen = na
var line bullishImbLow = na

var line bearishImbOpen = na
var line bearishImbHigh = na

bullishImb = low > high[2]
bearishImb = high < low[2]

barcolor(bullishImb ? BLUE : bearishImb ? YELLOW : na, offset = -1, title = "Imbalance Bar Color")

plotshape(bullishImb ? bullishImb : na, style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = GREEN, offset = -1, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(bullishImb ? bearishImb : na, style = shape.triangledown, location = location.abovebar, color = RED, offset = -1, size = size.tiny)

var box[] ImbBoxes = array.new_box()
var bool[] ImbType = array.new_bool()

var color bullColor = color.new(bullishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput)
var color bearColor = color.new(bearishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput)

if bullishImb and showImbalance
    array.push(ImbBoxes, box.new(left = time[1], top = low, right = time, bottom = high[2], extend = extend.none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, border_color = bullColor, border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = bullColor))
    array.push(ImbType, true)

if bearishImb and showImbalance
    array.push(ImbBoxes, box.new(left = time[1], top = low[2], right = time, bottom = high, extend = extend.none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, border_color = bearColor, border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = bearColor))
    array.push(ImbType, false)

if array.size(ImbBoxes) > 0
    for i = array.size(ImbBoxes) - 1 to 0
        typeIsBull = array.get(ImbType, i)
        t = box.get_top(array.get(ImbBoxes, i))
        b = box.get_bottom(array.get(ImbBoxes, i))
        box.set_right(array.get(ImbBoxes, i), time)
        if updateZonesWithPriceMovement
            if typeIsBull
                if b >= low
                    box.delete(array.remove(ImbBoxes, i))
                    array.remove(ImbType, i)
                else if t >= low
                    box.set_top(array.get(ImbBoxes,i), low)
            else
                if t <= high
                    box.delete(array.remove(ImbBoxes, i))
                    array.remove(ImbType, i)
                else if b <= high
                    box.set_bottom(array.get(ImbBoxes, i), high)

if array.size(ImbBoxes) > numberOfZonesInput
    box.delete(array.shift(ImbBoxes))
    array.shift(ImbType)
```

Comment: There was one error, that's been corrected where array.get instead of array.remove was used.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass check and create a new box, if your size exceeds the allowed number of 10 boxes, you delete the earliest created box of the same type, while on the chart it will not necessarily be the first created of two types, the first created can be a different type of box and you will remove the box from the middle. All of your boxes are extended until the end of the series and in your screenshot you can see that boxes 9 and 6 are removed, instead of boxes of the opposite type.

You need to remove the first created box from the common set of two types

```
if bullishImb and showImbalance
    array.push(bullishImbBox, box.new(left = time[1], top = low, right = time, bottom = high[2], extend = extend.none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, border_color = bullColor, border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = bullColor))
    if array.size(bullishImbBox) + array.size(bearishImbBox) > numberOfZonesInput
        box.delete(array.shift(box.all))

if bearishImb and showImbalance
    array.push(bearishImbBox, box.new(left = time[1], top = low[2], right = time, bottom = high, extend = extend.none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, border_color = bearColor, border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = bearColor))
    if array.size(bullishImbBox) + array.size(bearishImbBox) > numberOfZonesInput
        box.delete(array.shift(box.all))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As much as I understand, if there are more boxes like Supply & Demand zones, `box.all` is going to delete them too, right?

Comment: I have other zones (boxes) in my whole script, which means this code shouldn't touch anything else in the script

Comment: You could also use a single box array for both bull and bear imbalances, and have a secondary bool array which is used to store the imbalance type that corresponds to each box element, ie true = bull, false = bear. Then when you're updating the zones from price movement, you can first retrieve the type from the bool array in order to select which price movement direction you're testing for.

Comment: @rumpypumpydumpy, this is best way. Could you write it as an answer?